# Why does this window have square corners?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, gui, styles

On Windows 7 with the Aero theme, Notepad++'s **Preferences** window has square corners, no system menu icon, a close button, and a darker `1px` border. This window also has an `AlwaysOnTop` attribute.

[image: notepad++]
*(I resized the window to fit a width of `640px`.)*

Interestingly enough, you can copy this style to other windows using [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com). So, it would seem that there is no dirty tricks involved. However, I don't think I've seen this window style anywhere else.

Is using this style condemned by Microsoft? Does this type of window have a name?

---

*For the curious: Normal vs "Square"*

[image: normal]   [image: calculator]

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that the .NET framework will give a frame with rounded corners by default, and no-one really feels like changing it.

Comment: Because Apple has a patent on rounded corners.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's called a **Tool(bar) Window**. Any windows that have the [`WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx#ws_ex_toolwindow) extended style will be rendered without a system menu or minimize/maximize boxes, and a small titlebar. In Windows XP and up (that support themes), tool windows are usually rendered without rounded corners (at least with the default themes).

This style is usually used for toolbars (Figure 1). You can see it by dragging a toolbar off of a program that lets you rearrange the toolbars. Notice that it becomes a window that looks like the one in question. Windows Explorer also uses it for deskbands (Figure 2) which are basically the same thing. You can see these by dragging a folder to one of the screen edges, then drag the resulting toolbar/deskband out to the desktop.

Obviously some programs use the style for other purposes, often as a way of creating a sort of modal, temporary dialog that is a child to the main program.

Note: this has a couple of effects (the first two of which are usually the *reasons* for its non-standard usage):

- A window/dialog with this style does not get a button on the taskbar
- It prevents <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>bing to the dialog
- It also prevents the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> from capturing just the dialog; the whole parent program window is captured.

**Figure 1:** MSPaint toolbar window

[image]

**Figure 2:** Windows Explorer deskband

[image]

Comment: `Alt`+`PrintScreen` captures just the dialog in Windows 7 with the Notepad++ Preferences dialog.

Answer (score 17):

This details the name of this window style and the options available in .NET; see @Synetech's excellent answer for the original purpose of this window style, the reasons it may be used for such a dialog box and the implementation in unmanaged Windows programs such as Notepad++.

---

The window has square corners and looks like that because one of the designers/programmers of Notepad++ decided to use a specific window style. Synetech details the advantages of that window style.

In .NET/Visual Studio, this is set in the [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property of the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class. Specifically, it is the `FixedToolWindow`. The possible values are in the [`System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) enumeration.

The `ToolWindow`s in .NET with all values default work a little differently from a plain `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` in the Windows API, though they look the same. With testing, I have determined that they *do* appear on the taskbar and they *do* appear on the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> task switcher unless the form property `ShowInTaskbar` is set to `false`. `ShowInTaskbar` affects visibility in both the taskbar and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for `ToolWindow`s, but only taskbar for others.

Meanwhile, it is also possible to remove the icon/minimise/restore/maximise buttons from the more common window styles, though it does not seem to be possible to add them to `ToolWindow`s. It is also possible to hide normal windows from the taskbar.

The only functional advantage `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` offers, as far as I can tell, is that the window does not appear in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

---

I have included some screenshots comparing the .NET window styles. These are not directly used by Notepad++, nor other unmanaged programs, but *are* named by Microsoft, so...

Possible values of `FormBorderStyle`:

<sup>The first image is a screenshot of the running program with Aero enabled, the second is from the Visual Studio designer view (no Aero).</sup>
<sup>Click the images for the full size versions</sup>
<sup>Descriptions are taken from the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) on the `FormBorderStyle` enumeration.</sup>

- `None`

  > No border.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `FixedSingle`

  > A fixed, single-line border.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `Fixed3D`

  > A fixed, three-dimensional border.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `FixedDialog`

  > A thick, fixed dialog-style border.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `Sizable` (default)

  > A resizable border.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `FixedToolWindow`

  > A tool window border that is not resizable. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. Although forms that specify `FixedToolWindow` typically are not shown in the taskbar, you must also ensure that the `ShowInTaskbar` property is set to `false`, since its default value is `true`.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

- `SizableToolWindow`

  > A resizable tool window border. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot_Aero]
[image: Screenshot_NonAero]

Comment: Yeah! that what we was talking about.

Comment: It has nothing to do with managed/unmanaged or native/.NET code. It is simply a matter of how Windows styles windows with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style. .NET simply aliases `FixedToolWindow` to `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` and `SizableToolWindow` to `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_THICKFRAME`. No offence, but this answer doesn’t actually answer the question or explain the behavior asked, it is simply a list/[resource](http://www.cnblogs.com/wingfay/archive/2007/12/06/985552.html) of different [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) used in .NET.

Comment: @Synetech I am aware it has nothing to do with whether the code is managed or not, I just thought I would give the name .NET uses and the other options available, with screenshots of the differences. `Does this type of window have a name?` It does answer that much, at least from a .NET programmer's perspective. And explanation? Because the programmer felt like using it. You've listed possibly desired effects. That's about it. Whether it's recommended or condemned by MS, I have no idea. Personally, I think you've done an admirable job at explaining it.

Comment: That's what edits are for.

Comment: What's that @Synetech?